# How to execute .Jar file with VM Arguments on AdoptOpenJDK 11 & JavaFX 11?

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error, executable-jar

I need to export a short test application in `JAR` file but when I launch the app I have an error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check youe installation and try again

A Java Exception has occurred
```

This is my VM Arguments :

```
--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing

--add-opens
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I need all this arguments because I use :

- `AdoptOpenJDK 11 Hotspot`
- `JavaFX 11`

Without this vm arguments I can't run my app.

How I can export this VM Arguments to use my app with any PC ?

Comment: The error you have seems to be `JNI` related. Can you share the content of `Exception`? Maybe some native libraries are missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run it just like that:

```
> java --module-path modules --add-modules module_a,module_b -jar lib/your_jar_file.jar
```

Comment: Can I put that in a bash file? And how do I integrate --add-opens?

Comment: Or I can create a class to read this vm arguments at the launch state ?

Comment: Just create one, long, line: `java ... --add-modules ... --add-opens ...` etc.

Comment: Take a look here for various ways of calling code inside modules: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo064